# Get 2 or more data from 1 id in 1 table

Tags: mysql

i need help about sql query..
Sorry but I do not know much about sql, and I'm bad with english.

I have sql table like this.

```
|  ID  |  Data  |
|  1   |  abc   |
|  1   |  def   |
|  1   |  ghi   |
|  2   |  jkl   |
|  2   |  mno   |
|  3   |  pqr   |
|  3   |  stq   |
```

and i want result like this

```
|  ID  |       Data      |
|  1   |  abc, def, ghi  |
|  2   |  jkl, mno       |
|  3   |  stq, def       |
```

or like this

```
|  ID  |  Data1 |  Data2 |  Data3 |
|  1   |  abc   |  def   |  ghi   |
|  2   |  jkl   |  mno   |
|  3   |  pqr   |  stq   |
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: are you using SQL-Server or MySQL.

Comment: Couple of hints so that you can try yourself. You can use case / group by

Comment: research 'group by' and 'group_concat'... good luck

Comment: Don't tag products not involved! You've already got two product specific answers. (Don't waste people's time having them writing answers for "wrong" dbms.)

Comment: How do you determine which value appears in which column/order

Comment: oh,, I'm sorry for waste your time..
this is my random job, i don't know much about this..
I just edit the tag.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysql:

[group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is your friend.

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT id, group_concat(data) as data from my_table group by id
```

this produces results of the type in your first sample. The second sample output is more complicated,

Comment: @Suraz i missed the fact that this was tagged both as sql server and mysql

Comment: group_concat is nobody's friend :-(

Comment: oh,, I'm sorry for waste your time..
this is my random job, i don't know much about this..
Thank you for your answer, this is what I need..

Answer (score 2):

For Sql server:

```
select id,
stuff((select ','+data from #temp t2 where t1.id=t2.id for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as val from #temp t1
group by id
```

for mysql:

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(data)  
FROM table 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: @Suraz:no there is no group concat in SQLServer

Comment: Right, you have given answer in both sql-server and mysql, sorry I didn't notice

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query, it should work

```
select 
     t1.id,
     Data=STUFF((select ', '+t2.Data from test t2 where t1.id=t2.id for xml path('')),1,2,'')  
    from test t1
    group by t1.id
```

i try this query in sql server

Answer (score 0):

Use **Stuff function**:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 AS TABLE
 (
  Id INT,
  Data VARCHAR(50)
 )


 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,'abc')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,'def')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,'ghi')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2,'jkl')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2,'mno')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(3,'pqr')
 INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(3,'stu')

 SELECT
    Id,
    (
        SELECT 
        STUFF
        ( 
            (
                SELECT 
                    ',' + Data 
                FROM @tbl1 B                             
                WHERE A.Id=B.Id                             
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 
            1, 1, ''
        )
    ) AS Data
FROM @tbl1 A
GROUP By A.Id
```